# What does the notation in a max/min statement mean, in a generalized Lagrangian?

Tags: optimization, notation, lagrange-multiplier

I'm studying about Lagrange duality and I I have the following problem:

$$ \min_{w} f(w) $$
s.t. $$ h_i(w) = 0, i = 1,...,l $$
$$ g_i(w) \leq 0, i = 1,...,k $$

So, somewhere in the text says that I should consider this quantity:

$$ \theta_p(w) = \max_{\alpha,\beta:\alpha_i \geq 0} \mathcal{L}(w,\alpha,\beta) $$

My question is, how should I read and interpret that max statement in the latter formula? Is it max over alpha, beta where alpha and beta are positive, or just alpha is positive?

Comment: I read the colon as a ", where", i.e., the max over all $\alpha, \beta$ where the $\alpha_i$ must be non-negative (for all $i$, I would guess). No further constraint on $\beta$.

Comment: Thank you @Florian, makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on @Florian 's comment.

$\beta$ are unconstrained in the dual problem because they correspond to equality constraints in the primal (i.e., original) problem.

$\alpha$ are constrained to be non-negative in the dual problem because they correspond to $\le$ inequality constraints in the primal problem.